# Random even numbers on array from 1 to 100

Tags: java, random

I need to write on an array 20 random numbers from 1 to 100, but just even numbers.. For some reason i'm getting 0 on some array value, any solution for this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
    arregloAleatorio[i] = randomNumber; 
}
```

The print is, for example:

```
0 26 0 4 0 14 0 78 0 16 0 0 86 10 0 0 0 72 34 70
```

But I don't want 0 in the array.

Comment: That's because sometimes the result is odd, and you skip storing any value.  Thus, those values appear as 0 in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int[] arregloAleatorio = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(101);
    while (randomNumber % 2 != 0 || randomNumber == 0){
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(101);
    }
    arregloAleatorio[i] = randomNumber;
}
```

You are not adding a number to the array if it is odd, therefore by default it was zero.

This solution generates a random number until it is not 0 or odd.

Comment: Nit: You will never get the number 100. Use this instead, which will also obviate the need for the null check: `int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100) + 1;`

Comment: That might be not so efficient as you do not know how many random calls you are going to do. There is a tiny chance (~0%) that it will never end.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to think about the constraints first. We want to the generated numbers to be the even numbers, between 2 and 100. This group of numbers, is of the size of 50. Therefore, we can generate a random number between 0-49 (Inclusive), and then add 1 and multiply by 2, and get the required number. The code:

```
int[] arr = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(50) + 1
    arr[i] = randomNumber * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your iteration continues even if the number is odd, and when you are outputting the array, it appears to be a 0 because there is no number at that index! The quick fix would be to just decrement `i` if the number is odd. I am adding only 1 line of code. I didn't try it but it should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100) + 1;

    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
        
        arregloAleatorio[i] = randomNumber;
        
    }else i--;
```